# What's the difference between the actual solution vs my solution?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm new to SQL. Can anyone please tell me what's the difference between the actual solution vs my solution?

Schema: [image: 1]

Question:

> Compare the number of male managers to the number of female managers from different departments for each year, starting from 1990.

Output for the actual solution:

[image: 2]

The error I'm getting with my solution:

> Unknown column "calendar_year" in the field list

```sql
/* This is the actual solution */

SELECT
    d.dept_name,
    ee.gender,
    dm.emp_no,
    dm.from_date,
    dm.to_date,
    e.calendar_year,
    CASE 
        WHEN YEAR(dm.to_date) >= e.calendar_year AND YEAR(dm.from_date) <= e.calendar_year THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END AS active
    FROM 
    (SELECT 
        YEAR(hire_date) AS calendar_year
    FROM
        t_employees
    GROUP BY calendar_year) e
        CROSS JOIN
    t_dept_manager dm
        JOIN 
    t_departments d ON dm.dept_no = d.dept_no
       JOIN
    t_employees ee ON dm.emp_no = ee.emp_no
    ORDER BY dm.emp_no, calendar_year;
```

```sql
/* This is my solution */

SELECT
    d.dept_name,
    ee.gender,
    dm.emp_no,
    dm.from_date,
    dm.to_date,
    YEAR(e.hire_date) AS calendar_year,
    CASE
        WHEN
            YEAR(dm.to_date) >= calendar_year
                AND YEAR(dm.from_date) <= calendar_year
        THEN
            1
        ELSE 0
    END AS active
    FROM
    t_employees e
        CROSS JOIN
    t_dept_manager dm
        JOIN
    t_departments d ON dm.dept_no = d.dept_no
        JOIN
    t_employees ee ON dm.emp_no = ee.emp_no
    ORDER BY dm.emp_no , calendar_year;
```

Comment: You should edit the question and show the results of the two queries.

Comment: He dcan not show you anything because the second querie is flawed qas i stated im my downvoted answer. And teh question was at the start what is the difference .

Comment: you should do `<tablename reference>.<column_name>`; as @nbk referenced in their deleted answer . You also maybe have two entities both called "calendar_year"?

Comment: I wouldn't be happy with the first query specifically SELECT  YEAR(hire_date) AS calendar_year  FROM  t_employees GROUP BY calendar_year which assumes there is at least 1 employee hired every year from 1990